# How to get full string in .text() method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on javascript and html. I have table data. On the click of each td value I run a javascript function which get the text value of td and put as value in input tag generated dynamically. When I click the td text why I don't get the full string in my value?

I tried using inner Html and tried setting value.

```
 <tr class="success">
     <td id="name" ><a style="cursor: pointer;">Ravi Sharma</a></td> 
  </tr>
```

```
$('#name a').click(function() {
var name = $(this).text();
    var html = '<input type="text" name="memberlist" value='+ name +'/> ';

});
```

```
Expecting:

<input type="text" name="memberlist" value="Ravi Sharma" >

Actual:

<input type="text" name="memberlist" value="Ravi" sharma>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML element attributes need to have quotes around their values. When you are doing your concatenating the single quotes get interpolated. So it assumes the first word is the only value.

Instead of:
`var html = '<input type="text" name="memberlist" value='+ name +'/> ';`

Try:
`var html = '<input type="text" name="memberlist" value="'+ name +'"/> ';`

@ray-toal [brings up many good points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56202339/8920669) about sanitization of your inputs and defending against XSS.

Comment: That was quite a good knowledge. Thanks @axecopfire it worked

Answer (score 2):

Other answers will tell you *why* you got the result you did. It is tempting to try to solve the problem by just adding quotes, e.g.,

```
var html = '<input type="text" name="memberlist" value="'+ name +'"/> ';
```

This will work great if `name` is `Ravi Sharma`. But if you are constructing a chunk of HTML and trying to put the resulting string into an element's `innerHTML` you will have trouble if the variable `name` has double quotes in it!

```
name = 'Ravi O"Brien'

document.body.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="memberlist" value="'+ name +'"/> '
```

This will expand into

```
value="Ravi O"Brien"
```

and your input box will contain only "Ravi O".

Sure you can use backticks and interpolation to solve this, or you can even try escaping the double quote characters with backslashes. Doing so is error prone. `innerHTML` is problematic anyway, and a big security concern. It is preferable to create the HTML elements yourself. You are using jQuery so the proper way to create your input element is:

```
$("<input/>", {
    type: 'text',
    value: name,
    name: 'memberList',
})
```

There are ways to be safe with `innerHTML` but IMHO it should (always) be avoided.

Comment: That is a good explanation no doubt. But what if I had an array of names and wanted to create a list with those? Won't creating an element and appending it repeatedly inside a loop seem too hectic?

Comment: Not at all....I would find it clearer, personally. You are building objects in JavaScript and calling functions in JavaScript instead of mucking around with fragments of strings and assembling them together and always being very wary of where the quotes are, and which substrings need escaping. You should be able to find a way to make a whole bunch of HTML elements whose data comes from arrays. Try it! Loops and array functions like `forEach` and `map` will be needed whether you are dealing with strings or HTML element constructor functions. Keep working at it, and refactor where necessary. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just added an ID to the `<a>` tag (as it's the parent of the content text) and changed a bit of the JavaScript logic, hope it helps :

```js
var text = document.getElementById("aName").innerHTML;
var output = '<p>The name below is the result of the event, not the original state !</p>';
document.getElementById("aName").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.body.innerHTML = output + text;
});
```

```html
<tr class="success">
     <td id="name" ><a id="aName" style="cursor: pointer;">Ravi Sharma</a></td> 
  </tr>
```

**ALSO**, reading again what you're needing, to achieve what you want, you pretty much just have to apply the same logic to the tag inside the var, then call the var name on the `innerHTML` event :

```js
var text = document.getElementById("aName").innerHTML;
var input_txt = '<input type="text" name="memberlist" value="'+ text +'"/> ';
document.getElementById("aName").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.body.innerHTML = input_txt;
});
```

```html
<tr class="success">
     <td id="name" ><a id="aName" style="cursor: pointer;">Ravi Sharma</a></td> 
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting confused between the `single and double quotes` paring. I suggest using `backticks` as below:

```js
var name = 'Ravi Sharma';
var html = `<input type="text" name="memberlist" value="${name}"/> `;
console.log(html);
```

When ever you need to insert a variable just encapsulate it within `${}`. No more quotes pairing problems.

Comment: I tried it doesn't get the text . It simply takes ${name} not Ravi Sharma

Comment: @RaviSharma I'm pretty sure it works. I edited my answer and added a code snippet. Check it. Did you use the `\`\`` at the start and end?

Answer (score 0):

Reproduced your code and got answer. 
 1. Change string initialization from '' to `` to be able to interpolate variables. 
 2. In your expectations, you ask for '>', but code contains '/>' change that if needed.
3. Here your solution!

```
$('#name a').click(function() {
    var name = $(this).text();
    var html = `<input type="text" name="memberlist" value="${name}"/> `;
```

```js
"use strcit";


$('#name a').click(function() {
    var name = $(this).text();
    var html = `<input type="text" name="memberlist" value="${name}"/> `;
    console.log(html);
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
        <title>Stack Overflow</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
          <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <table class="table">
          <tr class="success">
              <td id="name" ><a style="cursor: pointer;">Ravi Sharma</a></td> 
          </tr>         
      </table>
      <script src="scripts/so.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers ignore the `<tbody>`, `<tr>`, and `<td>` tags and the corresponding end tags. This has not been specified in HTML specifications, since they do not define the parsing of syntactically erroneous documents. In the HTML5 draft, however, there is a description that defines the browser behavior in a manner that corresponds to the what browsers actually do: [Tree construction](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#tree-construction).

This means that you cannot write an HTML document that contains, say, a  element outside a table element. The HTML parser in a browser simply does not construct such document trees. (You can, however, construct such a document dynamically with client-side scription.)

```js
$('#name').click(function() {
    alert("asdfsdf");
    var name = $(this).text();
    var html = '<input type="text" name="memberlist" value='+ name +'/> ';
    
    $("#test").text(html);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr class="success">
     <td><a id="name" style="cursor: pointer;">Ravi Sharma</a></td> 
  </tr>
  
 <div id="test"></div>
```